# How to solve $ty' + y = t^2 \ln t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve  $ty' + y = t^2 \ln t$, $y(1) = 0$?
Here is my work so far but I am stumped. 
\begin{align}
\int ty'e^x+e^xy&=\int e^x t^2\ln t\\
ye^x&=
\end{align}

Comment: the factor $ ty' +y= d(ty) $

Comment: The independent variable is $t$, not $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your differential equation is already in a suitable form to apply the reverse product rule. Hence, one can substitute $1=\frac{d}{dt}(t)$ to obtain:
$$t\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{d}{dt}(t)\cdot y=t^2\ln{t}$$
Applying the reverse product rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(ty)=t^2\ln{t}$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $t$ and using integration by parts we obtain:
$$\begin{align} ty&=\int t^2\ln{t}~dt \\ &=\frac{1}{3}t^3\ln{t}-\frac{1}{3}\int t^2~dt\\ &=\frac{1}{3}t^3\ln{t}-\frac{t^3}{9}+C \end{align}$$
Hence, we have:
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{3}t^2\ln{t}-\frac{t^2}{9}+\frac{C}{t}$$
To incorportate the initial condition $y(1)=0$, substitute $t=1$ and $y=0$ and evaluate the value of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

In big words. BERNOULI'S

$$y'+\frac{y}{t}=t \ln t$$

Integrating Factor: $e^{\int\frac{dt}{t}}=t$
$$\int d(yt)=\int t^2\ln t.dt+C $$
To solve $\int t^2 \ln t$, take $t=e^x$ and proceed.

This shall give your answer

$$\int e^{2x}.x=\frac{1}{2}(x.e^{2x}-e^{2x})$$

Comment: Thanks! Isn't the integral of (e^2x)(x) = ((2x-1)(e^2x))/4  though? And then how would I incorporate y(1) = 0?

Comment: @Math.Student No. The integral is what I've calculated using integ. by parts. As for your second question. simplt $e^{2x}=t^2$ and $x=\ln t$

Comment: Integration by parts

Comment: @TheDeadLegend You made a mistake with the integration by parts. The OP is correct with his solution (Apart from the missing constant of integration).
$$\int e^{2x}\cdot x~dx=\frac{1}{2}xe^{2x}-\int \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} e^{2x}~dx=\frac{1}{2}xe^{2x}-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{2x}~dx=\frac{1}{2}xe^{2x}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2x}+C$$
By the way, if you mean that $y'+\frac{y}{t}=t\ln{t}$ is a Bernoulli differential equation, it is not. A Bernoulli differential equation is of the form:
$$y'+P(t)\cdot y=Q(t)\cdot y^n \qquad \qquad \text{where }n\in \mathbb{R}, n \neq 0,n\neq 1$$

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Also, you forgot to take into account that:
$$t=e^x \iff dt=e^x~dx$$
Therefore, even after your substitution, you will obtain:
$$\int t^2\ln{t}~dt=\int xe^{2x}\cdot e^{x}~dx=\int xe^{3x}~dx$$